# help understand diff between: sort < file.txt VS file.txt | sort

Tags: 12.04, server, redirect, pipe, sort

so im learning Ubuntu (for the first time) and am reading trough Ubuntu server book

chapter 14 says

`filename.txt | sort`
will give me an output with the content of the file, but sorted
HOWEVER it doesn't mention if i can type in:

`filename.txt | sort > sortedfilename.txt`
to create a new file this time with sorted content, Can i?

it does state that i could type in

`sort < filename.txt`

and again, get a sorted output of the files content
it continues to mention i can type in
`sort < filename.txt > sortedfilename.txt`

and create a file with sorted content

so are these two different ways to do the exact same thing?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in your example code that I'll just address first. `filename | ...` won't do anything other than blurt out an error and then confuse the thing on the other side of the pipe... unless that filename is also a global executable and then it's not doing what you wanted.

You'd need to `cat filename | ...`.

Just to muddy the waters, `sort` can also take a filename as an argument. You could (and should, if this is your actual use case) just run `sort filename > sortedfilename`.

---

Anyway, back to redirects...

The input redirect (`<`) reads from a file and pipes that into `stdin`. To answer your question, it is *directly* equivalent to `cat filename |`.

The `sort` command looks for `stdin` in lieu of a filename argument and does the sorting and pipes that to `stdout`. The output redirection (`>`) can then be used to send that into a file rather than the screen.

If you really want to blow your mind, read [TLDP's chapter on I/O redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). It's probably a bit more raw than your book but it's solid, tested stuff. Actually (having just read it again), its explanation is pretty decent.

The position of the input is a lot more fluid than statndard pipes. The following is valid:

```
< filename sort > sortedfilename
```

Comment: thank you very much! instead of just answering my question you also gave me a nice extra! much appreciated!